# working sprite collision

Tags: sprite, pygame, collision

I am having two problems with my code:

1. I don't know how to make my character check that it's colliding with the blocks
2. How do I blit to a new screen every time she completes a level? So when the character reaches the stair then a new screen should appear showing the new level

Here is all my code :

http://pastebin.com/u/bluesplay106

I am pretty new to pygame so my style may not be good and I kind of hard coded this game.
If you could tell me how to fix my problem that would be really great!!

Comment: Your questions are going to need to be much more specific if you hope to get an applicable answer.

Answer (score -1):

for the collision detection you need to make your character and your blocks into sprites and do a collision detection that way.

As for the new screen when you get to the stairs, you can use a statement like this:

```
if heroSprite_x >= 200 and heroSprite_x <= 300:
    if heroSprite_y >= 300 and heroSprite_y <= 400:

        #go to new screen using either a new level from a list or a new class or whatever method you want.
```

Your question was a bit vague but I hope that's what you were looking for :)

I just realized I didnt answer your first question, here's a snippet from one of my games:

```
unit_enemy = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(unitgroup, enemygroup, True, pygame.sprite.collide_mask) 

for hit in unit_enemy:
    #do something
```

This checks if any enemies hit my unit. So in you case it would be your hero, and the enemies would be blocks.

Here's the documentation on collision detection.

http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html